# Change orientation of landscape pages only in PDF

Tags: pdf, printing, landscape, portrait, pdftk

I have a PDF file exported from LibreOffice Writer. Here is an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z1uycb17ckd8bam/test.pdf?raw=1). Some pages have portrait orientation, and others have landscape orientation. I am using Linux, and when I view the file in evince or Foxit Reader, it is shown correctly,i.e., all text lines are horizontal. It is also printed correctly on my printer on A4 paper: landscape pages are rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise so that text lines become vertical.

The problem is: the document is going to be printed on another device (in a publisher), and I was told all pages must have portrait orientation. I am not sure if this is already the case and evince simply shows the landscape pages rotated clockwise. For example, `pdfinfo file.pdf` prints `Page rot: 0`. If so, then everything is fine. If, however, the PDF file has a command saying that the following page is in landscape mode, then it is necessary to rotate it by 90 degrees and declare it portrait.

So is it possible to rotate **only** landscape pages from the command line? I know I can do it with pdftk, but then I need to specify page numbers manually. I have a lot of documents and manually specifying landscape page numbers is hard. Is there an automatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with Python and module PyPDF2.
See an example code:

```
import PyPDF2

pdf_in = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_in)
pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

numofpages = pdf_reader.numPages

numrotated = 0 
for pagenum in range(numofpages):
    page = pdf_reader.getPage(pagenum)
    mb = page.mediaBox
    if (mb.upperRight[0] > mb.upperRight[1]) and (page.get('/Rotate') is None):
        page.rotateCounterClockwise(90)
        numrotated = numrotated + 1
    pdf_writer.addPage(page)

print str(numrotated) + " of " + str(numofpages) + " pages were rotated"
pdf_out = open('test_rotated.pdf', 'wb')
pdf_writer.write(pdf_out)
pdf_out.close()

pdf_in.close()
```

Tested on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, Python 2.7.12, PyPDF2 1.26.0.
Also works on Windows.

Comment: how to do with multiple pdf files ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer above but converted into python3

```
pdf_in = open('test.pdf', 'rb')
pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_in)
pdf_writer = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()

numofpages = len(pdf_reader.pages)

numrotated = 0
for pagenum in range(numofpages):
    page = pdf_reader.pages[pagenum]
    mb = page.mediabox
    if (mb.upper_right[0] > mb.upper_right[1]) and (page.get('/Rotate') is None):
        page.rotate(90)
        numrotated = numrotated + 1
    pdf_writer.add_page(page)

print (str(numrotated) + " of " + str(numofpages) + " pages were rotated")
pdf_out = open('test_rotated.pdf', 'wb')
pdf_writer.write(pdf_out)
pdf_out.close()

pdf_in.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).